# How to save the confidential data at server side

Tags: security, node.js, webserver

I create a web server with Node.js. The database is MongoDB. I'm using a json file to save the server configuration. The node module 'nconf' is used to read the json file.

Currently, all the data, including some confidential data, saved in the json file is plain text. I don't think it is security enough. What should I do to make sure the confidential data is security?

Comment: You don't trust those who have access to your server?  I would fix that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look into the `crypto` library of node.

Here is a link to the documentation: [Crypto Node.js](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html)

You could use this to encrypt some of the data that is contained within the file. But you should also probably consider removing the sensitive information and find another means to store it else where, perhaps within a database, like your MongoDB.